# Type search quries into firefox URL bar, and have it go through Google, NOT Bing

Tags: firefox

I know this is possible, how though?  I don't see it in the options, or anywhere else for that matter.  I am however able to get Google as the default search provider, but for some reason, that only applies to the search bar in the upper right corner search box.

Firefox ver: 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the default search engine.
Go to "about:config", and search for: "browser.search.defaultenginename"
Then edit it to say Google.

Comment: +1, but funny, Google is the default. He can also right-click the property and click "Reset".

Comment: click reset where?

Comment: Doesn't help.  It may be b/c I have a toolbar installed...

Answer (score 1):

With keyword searches, you have more options.
See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches